# Main page colorbox and facebook like box

Tags: 7, social-network, javascript

In my CakePHP site when user is first entered to my site, I check for a cookie. And if I can't find the cookie, after document load from my js file, I show Facebook like box to my visitors. I show a "div" that in invisible in my page.

I can't imagine how can I implement this in my Drupal 7 site.
Should i put the invisible div into one of my node. If so, how can I load it from main node that includes only links to inner nodes?

I would be very happy if you can write the steps or show an example of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [hook_boot()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7) to set/unset the visitor's cookie.
You can then use [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) to check the value of the cookie and execute some javascript to construct your div. Your javascript can be inserted in the page during hook_init() through [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7).

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion; Load your form or div that you want to display in the colorbox into a block region that would in any case be there. Then in `template.php` you can use an override function

```
function THEME_preprocess_block(&$variables){

  if($variables['block']->region == 'sidebar_second' && $variables['block']->delta == 6){
    //Do This
  }
}
```

OR create a block template file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put invisible `div` into each page, then you can add `div` in `page.tpl.php` file into your theme directory.

Or If you want to put invisible `div` into *front* page of the site, then you can put `div` into `page-front.tpl.php` file into your theme directory.